# Is it possible to mix themes in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to have neptune toolbar on classic themed ExtJS website.
Is this thing possible ? If so , How ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom theme derived from a classic theme and you could copy the toolbar styles to your custom theme folder.

```
sencha generate theme my-custom-theme
```

Then, on your project's config file found on project folder`/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg`, edit/add the following:

```
app.theme=my-custom-theme
#app.theme=ext-theme-classic
```

I assume you have generated your project through `Sencha CMD`. Copy the toolbar styles found on `packages/ext-theme-neptune/sass/var/toolbar` and/or `packages/ext-theme-neptune/sass/src/toolbar` to your custom theme.

Comment: Hi , 
I downloaded ExtJS GPL and used the css there. never used the sencha cmd.

Comment: oh, sorry. i don't know anything about that :( I have been using `Sencha CMD` from workspace and application generation until app deploy. can't help you with that.

Comment: Its well worth using Sencha Cmd to do SASS to style the overall theme, you can the do CSS fixes for anything not covered- it'll save a lot of time :)

Comment: you're right about that. actually, our first extjs4 project was not generated by Sencha CMD so i have created a new one through Sencha CMD and copied all the significant files to the new project and tadaa! my life gets easier :)