# EXTJS-applying a different theme to a specific component?

Tags: extjs

we use the ExtJS "gray" theme in our app, is there a way i can use the "Accessibility" theme for a specific component? a window which includes a very basic form

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mix themes in ExtJS 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695009/is-it-possible-to-mix-themes-in-extjs-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extjs theme is applied using CSS style sheets on certain html element types with certain classes. Once you load a second theme css into the same page, the first theme is overwritten completely.

So it is not possible to mix them in a single app.

You would have to use two HTML pages, which load different style sheets, but same ext.js, and use two different browser windows or an iframe.